# Aeroo reports: getting error with ir.actions.report.xml.report_type: 'aeroo'

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, aeroolib

there is an odoo system with a timesheet module (self-made) in it. How report part works: aeroo report template made — timesheet can be printed via using that template — everything's good. But there is a problem: usually we work with reports via interface as I said before (reports->aeroo reports), but I'd like to describe it via xml.

I've made a new record in the views section of module:

```
<record id="report_person_card_id" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
   <field name="name">doc print</field>
   <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
   <field name="report_name">person_card</field>
   <field name="report_type">aeroo</field>
   <field name="type">ir.actions.report.xml</field>
   <field name="in_format">oo-odt</field>
   <field name="tml_source">file</field>
   <field name="report_rml">/tabel2.odt</field>
   <field name="parser_state">default</field>
</record>
```

Unfortunately, it gives an error message:

```
ParseError: "Wrong value for ir.actions.report.xml.report_type: 'aeroo'" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/Tabel/views/tabel.xml:5, near
<record id="report_person_card_id" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="name">doc_print</field>
    <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
    <field name="report_name">person_card</field>
    <field name="report_type">aeroo</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.report.xml</field>
    <field name="in_format">oo-odt</field>
    <field name="tml_source">file</field>
    <field name="report_rml">/tabel2.odt</field>
    <field name="parser_state">default</field>
</record>
```

I've tried different report types from default (pdf) to odt, but nothing changed. I feel it may be somehow related to addons/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py, but can't say it for sure.

Any advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "report_aeroo" in 'depends' line in your **openerp**.py

example

'depends': ["base", "report_aeroo"],